# SpringFramework: Pointcut expression

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspectj

Could someone explain me this pointcut expression ? I'm mainly interested in part after concatenation(`&&`). From what I understand it means: "*Apply advice with each invoke of `play` method from `Instrument` class*". `Within` designator confines reach of it, but It's not clear enough to me what does it do ?

```
execution(* com.springinaction.springidol.Instrument.play(..))
          && within(com.springinaction.springidol.*)
```

Comment: It seems to me like that is redundant. I'm reading it as any method `play()` in the `com.springinaction.springidol` package.

Comment: It isn't redundant, the within clause restricts the aspect to executing from classes only inside the `com.springinaction.springidol` package. So only calls to the play method from within classes inside the `com.springinaction.springidol` package will be intercepted. If one would call the play method from `org.springinaction.springidol` the pointcut wouldn't match (as the execution occurs from a different package).